# Looking for rules to "Geomag: Magnetic Challenge" (2005)

Tags: untagged

I picked up a complete set of this 2005 game, missing the ruleset though.

On BoardGameGeek there's a nomination of it, for "Worst rules ever" and some basic info, but no rules to illustrate the nomination; and no forum --- clearly too unpopular.

The commentary on BGG is that the English is incomprehensible; Geomag being Swiss I'd hope the French and/or German ruleset are better. I can do with a legible scan/photo of most of its languages --- English, German, Dutch, French, Italian, Spanish. Any ideas?

Comment: only thing I have been able to find is that it is a 2 page rulebook

Comment: Indeed! 2page book in English version nominated as 'worst rules ever' on BGG. Thanks for trying...  I thought many would have the thing lying around, but then BGG listing over 50K (or was it 80K? same difference!) different games makes me pessimistic.